# What are Best Practice for Managing Presence in Firebase? value, vs. child_*?

Tags: firebase

I am developing a web app utilizing presence data. I am rendering an avatar on the page for each visitor which will include meta data such as signup status, chat state, and other potential user related info.

When the page loads, all present users will be listed via a ("value",fn) statement.

Once that is done, is it better to manage client layer changes via child_added, child_changed and child_removed functions or rewrite the whole avatar DOM elements over and over with each change via the original "value" call?

Naturally, this is easier but will I be inviting performance issues further on up the road?

Would love to hear how others handle presence beyond simply here or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to drop the "value" call altogether and only handle "child_added" events. The "child_added" event will be triggered for all the old *and* new data, so a separate "value" event listener is not required.

Comment: using once('value') along with on("child_added") will let you control when the first batch of data is loaded on the listener, for example, in the case where you want to show a loading message to the user while all your initial data gets loaded